# std::ostream need help with function

Tags: c++

i need someone who explain me these lines of code part by part and i need some help in using "ostream" with simple examples. thank you :).

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Telegram& t)
{
  os << "time: " << t.DispatchTime << "  Sender: " << t.Sender
     << "   Receiver: " << t.Receiver << "   Msg: " << t.Msg;

  return os;
}
```

UPDATE 1: when i use this function it doesnt compile and the error says:

std::ostream& class::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Telegram& t) must take exactly one argument

Comment: Which part don't you understand? One could write several pages to explain the above code. You need to be more specific about what, exactly, is unclear to you.

Comment: i dont know how to use that return type. i dont know almost anything about "ostream".

Comment: Do you have a book? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: i have ivor horton`s but it doesnt cover that subject very good.

Answer (score 7):

These line are simply adding the ability to handle Telegram objects to the standard output stream class.

When you add a new class and you want output streams like `cout` to intelligently handle them, you need to add a new `<<` operator method which has the new object type as the second argument.

What the code above is doing is exactly that. When you later execute the statements:

```
Telegram tg("Bob", "Hello, how are you?");
cout << tg;
```

that function in your question will be called with the stream as the first argument and your `tg` object as the second argument and it will then be able to output the data in a format suitable to the class.

This was actually one of the early C++ things I had trouble getting my head around. Although the class is supposed to be self-contained, you're actually adding something to a *different* class to handle the output. Once you understand why this is happening (because it's the `ostream` class that is responsible for outputting things rather than your own class), it will hopefully make sense.

---

*Hopefully* making it clearer with a simpler example:

```
1    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Telegram& t) {
2      os << "message: " << t.Msg;
3      return os;
4    }
```

Line 1 is simply the function definition. It allows you to return the stream itself (that you pass in) so you can chain `<<` segments. The `operator<<` is simply the function you're providing, which is the one called when you put `<< tg` into an output stream statement.

Line 2 uses more basic `<<` statements that have already been defined (in this case, whatever type Msg is, probably a string).

Then line 3 returns the stream, again to allow chaining of `<<` segments.

The basic idea is to provide `operator<<` functions that build on existing `operator<<` function for the data types that constitute your type.

---

And with a simple wrapper class containing just an `int`:

```
#include <iostream>

// This is my simple class.

class intWrapper {
    public:
        intWrapper (int x) { myInt = x; };
        int getInt (void) { return myInt; }
    private:
        int myInt;

    // Must be friend to access private members.

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const intWrapper&);
};

// The actual output function.

inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const intWrapper& t) {
    os << "int: " << t.myInt;
    return os;
}

// Main program for testing.
// Output with getter and with ostream.

int main (void) {
    class intWrapper x(7);
    std::cout << x.getInt() << std::endl;   // ostream already knows about int.
    std::cout << x << std::endl;            // And also intWrapper, due to the
                                            //   function declared above.
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
7
int: 7
```

the first by just calling the getter function to retrieve the integer, the second by calling the `<<` operator function we added to `ostream`.

Comment: `Telegram tg = new Telegram();`?  Are you mixing up your languages, pax?

Comment: the thing i think i dont understand is the second line "os<<t.msg" how that works?? os is the same type as cout???

Comment: @jose: yes, `os` is an `ostream` just like `cout` and it's passed in because you may want to use _any_ output stream, not just `cout`. As to the "I don't understand" comment, `ostream` already _knows_ how to output the type `t.msg` (probably a string). That's why I said you write an output function for your new type based on simpler types (that are the individual parts of your type and that ostream already knows about).

Comment: i get the idea but i can pass a "ostream" instance like a cout? or am i very confused? :(

Comment: @jose, you don't call `operator<<` directly. When you execute `cout << tg`, it's automatically translated into a call to `operator<<(cout,tg)` for you. There's a whole lot of other stuff going on to help with chaining of `<<` (like returning the ostream variable as well) but that's administrivia.

Comment: `Telegram tg();` isn't really an improvement on `Telegram tg = new Telegram();`... if you wanted to default-initialize a `Telegram` object that would be simply `Telegram tg;`.

Comment: Okay, @Ben, how does `Telegram tg("Bob","Hello");` do it for you? I almost regret having ever declared it now since it's really a side issue to the actual question but I appreciate the feedback. :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo:      suppose cout couldnt work with type MSG like "t.MSG" . even if i overload the "operator <<" for my class i couldnt do this?? : "cout<<t<<endl;" because cout ostream object cant handle the type MSG. so i have to use the overloaded operator in an ostream object that can handle that type???????????

Comment: That's right. If one of the types _within_ your type cannot be printed with `<<` (because it didn't add a function to `ostream`), you have to find another way to print it (such as `getInt()` in my final example) or just not print it (unfortunate but, if the writer of that subtype foolishly hasn't given you anything to work with, there's not much you can do).

Comment: Having said that, it's extremely rare for a class developer _not_ to provide those functions. And you can add them yourself most of the time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The function you posted (henceforth "the function") is an overload of the insertion operator, `operator <<`. It allows you to output an object of type `Telegram`, or any other type deriving from `Telegram` or convertible to a `Telegram`, to an output stream. This is similar in spirit to the common use of IO streams in C++:

```
std::cout << 0 << '\n';
```

Here you output the `int` 0 followed by the `char` newline to the standard output stream. With the function you posted you can now do something like

```
Telegram tel;  // if Telegram has a default constructor
std::cout << tel << '\n';
```

something you would otherwise not been able to do, because the standard C++ library doesn't know about your new `Telegram` type and so never defined how to output objects of this type.

In code:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Telegram& t)
```

The first line starts with the `inline` keyword. Presumably the function is defined in a header file, and so in that case you must use the `inline` keyword so the definition does not violate the one definition rule.

That is, every time you include the header in an implementation file you get the function defined for that implementation file. When the linker comes in to link together all the compiled object files it will find multiple definitions of the function, one in each implementation file that included the header with the function you posted. This is something C++ forbids; C++ demands a function may be implemented no more than one time, and exactly one time if you intend to call it.

The use of the `inline` keyword essentially asks the C++ compiler to make sure that function is not defined more than once in such a way that the linker jumps off its seat and complains about the ambiguity of multiple definitions to choose from.

Here I argue it's a bad idea to inline the function. It would be a better idea to remove the `inline` keyword and move the function definition to its own translation unit, or implementation file. This way the function will compile exactly once, as opposed to once for each implementation file that includes the header with the function.

Next you will notice that function is a free function, as opposed to a member function. This allows (requires, as a matter of fact) the function to specify the operator's left operand, the stream object. This means the function will work with any object that is convertible to a stream. It also means you don't need to modify a class to add this extension to output semantics. If the function would be a member then you'd have to change the header of the class, which in turns means recompiling all implementation files that include that header. Granted, it appears your function is defined in a header; that's probably a bad idea, as I explained above.

Next you see that the function returns a `std::ostream`. `std::ostream` is in fact typedef'd as `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >`, and therefore your function can only output `Telegram` objects to streams that work on `char` types.

The reason the function returns a `std::ostream` is so that you can chain calls to the function. If you look carefully,

```
std::cout << 0 << 1;
```

is in fact a chain of two calls to the insertion operator overload function. Once to output 0, and then to output 1. It is equivalent to

```
std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, 0), 1);
```

The first call to insert 0 returns an output stream, and the second call to insert 1 takes that returned output stream and inserts into that 1. That's why we return the output stream: so we can chain calls.

You will also note that the insertion operator has a left-to-right associativity, which means that in the above statement 0 is guaranteed to be output first, and 1 second. This as opposed to the equivalent line I wrote above, in which the associativity (of function calls) is inside-out. This yields a much less readable code IMO, and that's one of the benefits of using `operator <<` for output semantics.

Next look at the function's parameters. The first parameter, a `std::ostream`, is taken by reference. This so you can change the stream. That's also why the stream is not taken by `const` reference.

The second parameter *can* be taken by `const` reference, because we don't want to change it, just read it. However, we do want to take it by reference, again because we don't intend to change it, not even for a local purpose, and so saving the construction of a copy can only be a good idea. It also allows for accepting derivatives of `Telegram` and caling virtual functions upon them, should the need arise. Also, taking a `const` reference allows you to output a temporary, as in `std::cout << Telegram() << '\n';`.

```
{
  os << "time: " << t.DispatchTime << "  Sender: " << t.Sender
     << "   Receiver: " << t.Receiver << "   Msg: " << t.Msg;
```

This code should be self explanatory now. Presumably each of the members you insert into the output stream has the insertion operator defined for. The standard library defines insertion into output streams for primitives, for strings, for complex numbers and other standard types.

```
  return os;
}
```

And finally you return the stream object, so the caller can chain the output with outputting another object. Note that you could simply return the result of the chain:

```
  return os << "time: " << t.DispatchTime << "  Sender: " << t.Sender
            << "   Receiver: " << t.Receiver << "   Msg: " << t.Msg;
```

Finally, to demonstrate the bonus you get from the use of a free function and taking the `Telegram` parameter by reference, consider:

```
struct Telegram {
    Telegram();
    Telegram(const Communication& c);
    virtual ~Telegram();
};

struct Message : public Telegram {
};

struct Letter {
    operator Telegram() const;
};

// ...
Telegram t;
Communication c;
Message m;
Letter l;

std::cout << t << '\n'
          << c << '\n'
          << m << '\n'
          << l << '\n';
```

All using that single function for outputting a `Telegram` object.

Comment: when i use my function my compiler says:  `std::ostream& telegram::operator<<(std::ostream&, const telegram&)' must take exactly one argument. why this happen?????

Comment: It should be a free function, not a member of `Telegram`.